# Convert simple lua code to C#

Tags: c#, lua

I have a simple code in lua which I need to translate into C# but I am unable to do it since I don't understand lua code. 
The code is:

```
function ToText(str)
  local res = ""
  local dtable = "4\rw+6d\b2aQ9\025\006Lu35\"$xPS)[@Y\024'G7U\001c\000W>1ti*=\021\020kB&\004e\019\031pE%D`H\003.<\016\026\023\017bN:\a,8(jm{\028r\014l- ]v\002f|\029R\vZy\005V^\n#C}~g_oz;\030hO\\As\f0!/X?\tMq\022IKTn\018\027J\015F"
  for i = 1, #str do
    local b = str:byte(i)
    if b > 0 and b <= 127 then
      res = res .. string.char(dtable:byte(b))
    else
      res = res .. string.char(b)
    end
  end
  return res
end
```

Comment: I'm afraid we're not here to write code for you. If you have a problem in your code, feel free to ask!

Comment: Yes, I have a problem in the code since I don't know what this means: local b = str:byte(i)
res = res .. string.char(dtable:byte(b))
In the matter of C# language.

Comment: All Lua string literals must be [converted to C#](http://rextester.com/YXIN63637), after that you can use them in [decoder](http://rextester.com/PBL38622)

Comment: More correct version of [decoder](http://rextester.com/YID60291)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You saved my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word-by-word translation would be roughly this, although i am still unsure on this `dtable` variable you might want to check how LUA does escaping.

```
public static string ToText(this string str)
{
  var result = new StringBuilder();
  var dtable = "4\rw+6d\b2aQ9\025\006Lu35\"$xPS)[@Y\024'G7U\001c\000W>1ti*=\021\020kB&\004e\019\031pE%D`H\003.<\016\026\023\017bN:\a,8(jm{\028r\014l- ]v\002f|\029R\vZy\005V^\n#C}~g_oz;\030hO\\As\f0!/X?\tMq\022IKTn\018\027J\015F";

foreach(Char c in str)
{
  var byteValue = Convert.ToByte(c);
  if(byteValue > 0 && byteValue <= 127(
  {
    result.Append(dtable[byteValue]);
  }
  else
  {
    result.Append(c);
  }
 }

return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I got the similar code but even your code returns some strange characters and not the readable code. So for example the input is:

string stri = "\022&\t!'Ol0O3K'@M'e'&Oz\tO%\017OH0&K\015DO\teOQO!\tl&'O['\006'&0OpO\026d\015Ol00O\015Q'\006'lDO!dOl0Oe\0060Oz\t!h\te':";

And the output should be:

Staci se priblizit na 15 metru, az v casti Vidite / You see uvidis, co se zde nachazi.

But is:

==0Q'1.1i. H1 01m10.9Q.  *2.%i0H *13.Qm. .'Q101.11 i 10i. . = j *1.1ii. *1 1 i 113.'j.1i.m i i.9Q'2Qm1B

Comment: @JimMasters That's coz your input as well as the dtable is somehow encoded (looks unicode like). so you need to find this encoding and replace dtable and input string. Kind of like i said in the answer, you need to check on escaping (and/or encoding).

Comment: Sounds like not so easy job, but I will do my best. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @JimMasters It kind of looks like ASCII OCTAL but hard to say for sure.

Comment: I will try to google in it a little bit but if not succeeded then I will probably use the original lua code and try the http://nlua.org/ to use it within C#.

Comment: C# strings are 0-based when indexing a single character inside it